# javascript (jQuery) - Single script is not working my in my 2 separate page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have two separate pages : `issuance_filter.php` and `memo_list.php` and 1 script . My problem is, I can't make it work on the `issuance_filter.php` but works perfect in `memo_list.php` . But sometimes it works vice versa.

Here's my code :

issuance_filter.php

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" class="init">

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "order": [[ 0, "desc" ]]
    } );
} );

</script>

<h2>Issuances</h2>

<table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th width="8%">ID</th>
            <th width="18%">Issuance Type</th>
            <th width="18%">Category</th>
            <th width="18%">In Charge</th>
            <th width="18%">Date Released</th>
            <th align="18%">Issuance Title</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

        <?php

            include "../dbconnect/dbconnection2015.php";
            mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");          
            /////////////////////////////////

            /*Values from the other page*/
                $type = htmlentities($_POST['type']);
                $year = htmlentities($_POST['year']);
                $in_charge = htmlentities($_POST['in_charge']);
                $category = htmlentities($_POST['category']);
                mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");

                if (empty($type) AND !empty($year) AND !empty($category) AND !empty($in_charge)) { 
                    $filter = "WHERE Year = '$year' AND Category = '$category' AND In_Charge = '$in_charge'";
                }
                elseif(empty($year) AND !empty($type) AND !empty($in_charge) AND !empty($category)){
                    $filter = "WHERE Issuance_Type = '$type' AND Category = '$category' AND In_Charge = '$in_charge'";
                }
                elseif(empty($in_charge) AND !empty($year)  AND !empty($type)  AND !empty($category)){
                    $filter = "WHERE Year = '$year' AND Category = '$category' AND Issuance_Type = '$type'";
                }
                elseif(empty($category) AND !empty($year) AND !empty($type) AND !empty($in_charge)){
                    $filter = "WHERE Year = '$year' AND Issuance_Type = '$type' AND In_Charge = '$in_charge'";
                }
                elseif(empty($type) AND empty($year) AND !empty($in_charge)  AND !empty($category)){
                    $filter = "WHERE Category = '$category' AND In_Charge = '$in_charge'";
                }
                elseif(empty($in_charge) AND empty($category) AND !empty($year) AND !empty($type)){
                    $filter = "WHERE Year = '$year' AND Issuance_Type = '$type'";
                }
                elseif(empty($type) AND empty($in_charge) AND !empty($year) AND !empty($category)){
                    $filter = "WHERE Category = '$category' AND Year = '$year'";
                }
                elseif(empty($category) AND empty($year) AND !empty($in_charge) AND !empty($type)){
                    $filter = "In_Charge = '$in_charge' AND Issuance_Type = '$type'";
                }
                elseif(empty($type) AND empty($category) AND !empty($in_charge) AND !empty($year)){
                    $filter = "WHERE In_Charge = '$in_charge' AND Year = '$year' ";
                }
                elseif(empty($in_charge) AND empty($year) AND !empty($type) AND !empty($category)){
                    $filter = "WHERE Category = '$category' AND Issuance_Type = '$type'";
                }
                elseif(!empty($type) AND empty($year) AND empty($category) AND empty($in_charge)){
                    $filter = "WHERE Issuance_Type = '$type'";
                }
                elseif(!empty($year) AND empty($type) AND empty($category) AND empty($in_charge)){
                    $filter = "WHERE Year = '$year'";
                }
                elseif(!empty($category) AND empty($year) AND empty($type) AND empty($in_charge)){
                    $filter = "WHERE Category = '$category'";
                }
                elseif(!empty($in_charge) AND empty($year) AND empty($category) AND empty($year)){
                    $filter = "WHERE In_Charge = '$in_charge'";
                }
                elseif(!empty($type) AND !empty($in_charge) AND !empty($year) AND !empty($category)) {
                    $filter = "WHERE Issuance_Type = '$type' AND In_Charge = '$in_charge' AND Year = '$year' AND Category = '$category'";
                }
                else{
                    $filter = "";
                }
                // echo $filter;

                $sql = "SELECT * FROM issuances $filter ORDER BY Issuance_ID DESC";
                $fetch_num_memo = mysql_query($sql);
                if ($fetch_num_memo && mysql_num_rows($fetch_num_memo) > 0){
                        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($fetch_num_memo)){
                        $string = $row['Issuance_Heading'];                     
                        echo "<tr>";
                        echo "<td>".$row['Issuance_ID']."</td>";    
                        echo "<td>".$row['Issuance_Type']."</td>";
                        echo "<td>".$row['Category']."</td>";
                        echo "<td>".$row['In_Charge']."</td>";
                        echo "<td>".$row['Date_Released']."</td>";
                        echo "<td><a class='filename' href='{$row['URL']}' target='_blank'>{$row['Issuance_Title']}</a></td></tr>";
                    }
                }
                else {
                    # Do Nothing
                }
        ?>
    </tbody>                        
</table>
```

memo_list.php

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" class="init">

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "order": [[ 0, "desc" ]]
    } );
} );

</script>

<h2>Issuances</h2>

<table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th width="5%">ID</th>
            <th width="15%">Issuance Type</th>
            <th width="15%">Date Released</th>
            <th align="15%">Issuance Title</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

        <?php

            include "dbconnect/dbconnection2015.php";
            mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
            $fetch_num_memo = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM issuances WHERE $filter ORDER BY Issuance_ID DESC");
            if ($fetch_num_memo && mysql_num_rows($fetch_num_memo) > 0){
                while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($fetch_num_memo)){
                $string = $row['Issuance_Heading'];                     
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>{$row['Issuance_ID']}</td>";  
                echo "<td> {$row['Issuance_Type']}</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['Month'].". ".$row['Date'].", ".$row['Year']."</td>";
                echo "<td><a class='filename' href='{$row['URL']}' target='_blank'>{$row['Issuance_Title']}</a></td></tr>";
                }
            }
            else {
            echo '<script type="text/javascript">
            window.location = "sdo_issuances.php"
            </script>';
            }
        ?>

    <tbody>                        
</table>
```

and the script :

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.filename').click(function(){
        var filename = ($(this).text());
         $.post('sdo_insert.php', {postname:filename}, function (data) {
                // $('.insert').html(data);
         });
         alert('You clicked : ' + filename);
       });
    });
</script>
```

I can't make the script works in both pages and can't figure out the problem. Please help me solve this one. Thanks

Comment: Did you try using developer toolbar to check if the script is loaded or not? Where is the final script written? Is it inline or in an external file? If external file, how's that referred in both pages?

Comment: i wrote the script in the end of the page. It is an internal script so i wrote it in both pages. And also , I tried the developer tools in firefox and the script was loaded.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  <script type='text/javascript'>
    $(function() {
    $('.filename').click(function(){
     var filename = ($(this).text());
     $.post('sdo_insert.php', {postname:filename}, function (data) {
            // $('.insert').html(data);
     });
     alert('You clicked : ' + filename);
   });
  });
</script>
```